# Red Hat 6.6, OpenLDAP, ldaps not responding

Tags: ssl, redhat, ldap, openldap

I'm having a hard time migrating our openldap installation from Debian to RedHat.

Two instances of openldap are running, they have the same configuration, except that one handles ldap: requests, and the other one ldaps: requests.

netstat shows that they are both listening:

```
sudo netstat -avp --tcp | grep ldap
tcp        0      0 *:ldap                      *:*                         LISTEN      11348/slapd
tcp        0      0 vldap-test-1.ceti.etat-:ssh 10.137.79.116:50842         ESTABLISHED 10461/sshd
tcp        0      0 vldap-test-1.ceti.etat-:ssh 10.137.79.116:49164         ESTABLISHED 7993/sshd
tcp        0     64 vldap-test-1.ceti.etat-:ssh 10.137.79.116:50815         ESTABLISHED 10281/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:ldaps                     *:*                         LISTEN      11344/slapd
tcp        0      0 *:ldap                      *:*                         LISTEN      11348/slapd
```

I'm not sure why two lines are shown for ldap, and only one for ldaps... whatever...

The ldap: requests work fine, but the ldaps: requests don't.

What's more puzzling, is that when I type the following command:

```
sudo openssl s_client -connect vldap-test-1:636 -showcerts
```

Or, with the IP address:

```
sudo openssl s_client -connect 10.145.24.112:636 -showcerts
```

I'm getting:

```
socket: Connection refused
connect:errno=111
```

whereas when I use localhost (not 127.0.0.1):

```
sudo openssl s_client -connect localhost:636 -showcerts
```

I'm getting:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = vldap-test, OU = DGSI, O = Etat, L = GE, ST = GE, C = CH
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = vldap-test, OU = DGSI, O = Etat, L = GE, ST = GE, C = CH
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=vldap-test/OU=DGSI/O=Etat/L=GE/ST=GE/C=CH
   i:/CN=vldap-test/OU=DGSI/O=Etat/L=GE/ST=GE/C=CH
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICOzCCAaSgAwIBAgICBNIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwWjETMBEGA1UEAxMKdmxk
YXAtdGVzdDENMAsGA1UECxMEREdTSTENMAsGA1UEChMERXRhdDELMAkGA1UEBxMC
... etc...
```

Can anyone help me understand what's happening here?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

It seems that the ldap: instance is listening both IPv6 and IPv4 but the ldaps: version is listening only IPv6.

How can I fix this?

Comment: First thought with an error message: `Connection refused` is a firewall blocking the connection.

Comment: I doubt it: I'm running these commands on the server itself. Oh, BTW, there is nothing in the IP tables.

Answer (score 0):

Got it: the IPv4 port was attributed to portreserve.